# Javascript cant access object property

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
 let test = {0:{
    firstProp:1,
    secondProp:2
}}
```

The problem is I cant access it like this:

```
test.0 

It always gives me error:
unexpected token, expected ","
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of `Property accessors` in **javascript** world

### Dot Notation

In the `object.property` syntax, the property must be a valid JavaScript [identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/identifier).

### Bracket Notation

In the `object[property_name]` syntax, the `property_name` is just a string or Symbol. So, it can be any string, including `'1foo'`, `1`, `'!bar!'`, or even `' '` (space).

so in your case, you need to use the bracket notation `[]` instead.

```js
let test = {
  0:{
    firstProp:1,
    secondProp:2
  }
};

console.log(test[0]);
```

For more details checkout **mdn** [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: Thank you it worked , I will be able to accept ur answer in 11 minutes